# Printing the content of a div with vertical scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

I have a div which has a fixed height and the content in it occupies more space than it's fixed height so I gave it an `overflow-y:scroll` . How do I print the entire content that is inside this div?

Comment: How have you specified the fixed height? Also what do you mean with printing "the entire content"?

Comment: Print, like in printing to paper on an actualy printer? If so, you use a different style for print ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you just override the scroll and height settings for print, without breaking the rest of the page layout?

```
@media print {
  #mydiv {
    height: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}
```